# Why the shape of my Numpy array is being returned as ()

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

```
first = input("please enter 5x2 matrix \n")    

first = np.array(first)
        
second = input("please enter 5x1 matrix \n")  
       
second = np.array(second)
    
print(first.shape)
    
print(second.shape)
```

The output i get is:

please enter 5x2 matrix

```
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]]
```

please enter 5x1 matrix

```
[[0],[0],[1],[0],[0]]


()

()
```

the dimension of my matrices are 5x2 and 5x1 but why doesn't the shape attribute display the dimensions correctly?

Comment: the 2 matrices below the "please enter...." is what i input from the keyboard during runtime

Comment: What you enter is a string, not a matrix. You cannot create an array out of it. At least not directly.

Comment: it does, thank you. Also can i clarify that there is no way to directly enter a numpy 2d array from the keyboard during input?

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: Thank you. Really appreciate this. Really useful to get this sorted while im still learning the basics.

Comment: The `np.matrix` subclass can parse a simple string: `np.matrix( '1 2; 3 4' ).A`.  It's trying to imitate MATLAB.   But usually, for testing, we just write code like `np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)`.